# Textview links with and without <a> tag

Tags: android, html, textview

I am trying to make these links text clickable in `TexView`.

```
String s = "<a href=\"https://google.com\">google</a> https://google.com";
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

I could not make both clickable at the same time.

This makes `<a>` tag clickable

```
textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

This makes web link clickable

```
textview.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
```

Comment: I have fixed with changing links (`https://google.com`) to (`<a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>`) but i don't know if its efficient

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/txtCredits"
    android:autoLink="web" android:id="@+id/infoTxtCredits"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:linksClickable="true"></TextView>

<string name="txtCredits"><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></string>

you have to add   android:autoLink="web" in our application
```

Comment: I need links without <a> tag to be clickable as well